# Autodesk setreference for child assemblies not working

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I am having trouble referencing child assemblies that are required for a parent assembly translation.

First I `POST` to `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/references/v1/setreference` with the following body

```
{ master: 'urn:adsk.objects:os.object:stemn/57b9f339c77fe2652f830206-ckwdob3791d6u359wz7eklnmi.iam',
     dependencies: 
      [ { file: 'urn:adsk.objects:os.object:stemn/57b9f339c77fe2652f830206-e3l7hokp0qxqn227b7qcjo47vi.iam',
          metadata: 
           { childPath: 'fuselage.iam',
             parentPath: '57b9f339c77fe2652f830206-ckwdob3791d6u359wz7eklnmi.iam' } },
        { file: 'urn:adsk.objects:os.object:stemn/57b9f339c77fe2652f830206-mhrb7um0of74iasv37nzh0k9.iam',
          metadata: 
           { childPath: 'motor_mount.iam',
             parentPath: '57b9f339c77fe2652f830206-ckwdob3791d6u359wz7eklnmi.iam' } } ] }
```

After setting references, I request translation and get the following result of the translation:

```
{ Result: 'Success',
  Scope: '25660970-8194-4de0-baa4-c8f1f132b2a7',
  RegisterType: [ 'thumbnail', '2dviewing', '3dviewing' ] }
```

After that I get the manifest for the urn and it is as follows:

```
{ guid: 'dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6c3RlbW4vNTdiOWYzMzljNzdmZTI2NTJmODMwMjA2LWNrd2RvYjM3OTFkNnUzNTl3ejdla2xubWkuaWFt',
  owner: 'dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6c3RlbW4vNTdiOWYzMzljNzdmZTI2NTJmODMwMjA2LWNrd2RvYjM3OTFkNnUzNTl3ejdla2xubWkuaWFt',
  type: 'design',
  hasThumbnail: 'false',
  startedAt: 'Wed Jan 04 04:43:59 UTC 2017',
  urn: 'dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6c3RlbW4vNTdiOWYzMzljNzdmZTI2NTJmODMwMjA2LWNrd2RvYjM3OTFkNnUzNTl3ejdla2xubWkuaWFt',
  region: 'US',
  status: 'failed',
  progress: 'complete',
  success: '100%',
  children: 
   [ { guid: 'aa85aad6-c480-4a35-9cbf-4cf5994a25ba',
       messages: 
        [ { type: 'warning',
            message: 'The drawing\'s thumbnails were not properly created.',
            code: 'TranslationWorker-ThumbnailGenerationFailed' } ],
       name: '57b9f339c77fe2652f830206-ckwdob3791d6u359wz7eklnmi.iam',
       success: '100%',
       hasThumbnail: 'false',
       role: 'viewable',
       version: '2.0',
       urn: 'dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6c3RlbW4vNTdiOWYzMzljNzdmZTI2NTJmODMwMjA2LWNrd2RvYjM3OTFkNnUzNTl3ejdla2xubWkuaWFt',
       status: 'failed',
       assetCount: 25,
       type: 'folder',
       progress: 'complete',
       children: 
        [ { guid: '015896d9-e6d3-4be6-8f3d-96da5e64eed3',
            type: 'folder',
            name: 'Scenes',
            status: 'success',
            progress: 'complete',
            success: '100%',
            hasThumbnail: 'false',
            children: 
             [ { guid: '451f7aab-1917-40dd-b117-5dd8f90ab6a7',
                 type: 'geometry',
                 role: '3d',
                 name: 'Scene',
                 status: 'success',
                 messages: 
                  [ { type: 'warning',
                      code: 'ATF-1023',
                      message: 
                       [ 'The file: {0} does not exist.',
                         'X:\\Google Drive\\SCAAD\\PRJ_HAARDCraft\\HAARDCraft_JFlight\\CAD\\Fuselage\\fuselage.iam' ] },
                    { type: 'warning',
                      code: 'ATF-1023',
                      message: 
                       [ 'The file: {0} does not exist.',
                         'X:\\Google Drive\\SCAAD\\PRJ_HAARDCraft\\HAARDCraft_JFlight\\CAD\\Engine mount\\motor_mount.iam' ] },
                    { type: 'error',
                      code: 'ATF-1026',
                      message: 
                       [ 'The file: {0} is empty.',
                         'C:/worker/viewing-inventor-lmv/tmp/job-1/68/output/1/57b9f339c77fe2652f830206-ckwdob3791d6u359wz7eklnmi.svf' ] } ],
                 size: 27864,
                 progress: 'complete',
                 success: '100%',
                 hasThumbnail: 'false',
                 children: 
                  [ { guid: '6dc4b244-8a47-4a75-bcb3-811dc7b4f294',
                      type: 'resource',
                      urn: 'urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6c3RlbW4vNTdiOWYzMzljNzdmZTI2NTJmODMwMjA2LWNrd2RvYjM3OTFkNnUzNTl3ejdla2xubWkuaWFt/output/1/57b9f339c77fe2652f830206-ckwdob3791d6u359wz7eklnmi.svf',
                      role: 'graphics',
                      mime: 'application/autodesk-svf',
                      size: 27864 } ] },
               { guid: '9bb1adbe-d9d9-4482-ac03-1d60bb0aea36',
                 type: 'resource',
                 urn: 'urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6c3RlbW4vNTdiOWYzMzljNzdmZTI2NTJmODMwMjA2LWNrd2RvYjM3OTFkNnUzNTl3ejdla2xubWkuaWFt/output/1/properties.db',
                 role: 'Autodesk.CloudPlatform.PropertyDatabase',
                 mime: 'application/autodesk-db',
                 status: 'success',
                 size: 24576 } ] },
          { guid: '039c2bcf-beb7-426b-916c-4a5adb814593',
            type: 'resource',
            role: 'Autodesk.CloudPlatform.DesignDescription',
            urn: 'urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6c3RlbW4vNTdiOWYzMzljNzdmZTI2NTJmODMwMjA2LWNrd2RvYjM3OTFkNnUzNTl3ejdla2xubWkuaWFt/output/xref/designDescription.json',
            mime: 'application/json' } ] } ] }
```

Using the same code path I can successfully render an assembly with non-assembly child parts that have been set using `setreference`, but when rendering an assembly with child assemblies, `setreference` doesn't seem to set the references to the child assembly files successfully. Is there something wrong in my sequence for setting references to child assemblies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discussed with @sabrehage and finally got the working codes.

firstly, it is recommended to use Forge Derivative API v2 (zip + specify root file only), by which, the API user does not need to specify the references explicitly.

If you still want to use Forge Derivative API v1, the following is the note:

In local Inventor, the file references are managed by Inventor Project. Inventor will look for the ref files firstly in the specific folders of the Project, then look for the relative paths. Obviously, when the files are uploaded to bucket of Forge, no project file, all files are in the same level in physical perspective. So in v1, it depends on the reference file that the sender specifies.

If the hierarchy is like:

```
Top Assembly.iam
    part1.ipt
    part2.ipt
```

The reference file can be simply composed like what is mentioned in the blog:
http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/09/how-to-set-references-with-inventor-files-for-view-and-data-api.html.

In the dataset of @sabrehagen, the hierarchy contains nested assemblies, even in sub folder:

```
topassemb.iam
    part in top assemb.ipt
    subassem folder
        subassem.iam
        part1 in sub assem1.ipt
        part2 in sub assem1.ipt
```

The correct way is to specify in one call (for top assembly only), and specify the subfolder in the reference map. In addition, we should define path name with original name, instead of that has been URL encoded. i.e.

```
{
    "master" : "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:adsk2017-8/topassemb.iam",
    "dependencies" : [
        {
            "file" : "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:adsk2017-8/subassem.iam",
            "metadata" : {
                "childPath" : "subassem/subassem.iam",
                "parentPath" : "topassemb.iam"
                }
        },
        {
            "file" : "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:adsk2017-8/part1%20in%20sub%20assem1.ipt",
            "metadata" : {
                "childPath" : "part1 in sub assem1.ipt",
                "parentPath" : "subassem/subassem.iam"
                }
        },
        {
            "file" : "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:adsk2017-8/part2%20in%20sub%20assem1.ipt",
            "metadata" : {
                "childPath" : "part2 in sub assem1.ipt",
                "parentPath" : "subassem/subassem.iam"
                }
        },
        {
            "file" : "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:adsk2017-8/part%20in%20top%20assemb.ipt",
            "metadata" : {
                "childPath" : "part in top assemb.ipt",
                "parentPath" : "topassemb.iam"
                }
        } 
    ]
}
```

If without specifying subfolder, Forge thinks all files are within the same level, but it conflicts to the hierarchy of the last saving (absolute path). So it failed to find the corresponding files in the bucket.

After Forge gets the files and correct reference, it will look at the reference file and create the subfolders if they are specified, then put those files to the subfolder from bucket, finally translate.

Answer (score 0):

as I remember, you would also need to configure the parts in the  web service of set reference. This is a blog: http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/09/how-to-set-references-with-inventor-files-for-view-and-data-api.html. probably it could help you to diagnose the issue. 
But, I strongly suggest you migrate to v2, by which you do not need to set reference manually. you can just upload all dataset as a zip file and set which file is the top (root) file, Forge will analyze the hierarchy automatically. This is another blog: http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/07/translate-referenced-files-by-derivative-api.html

Comment: Thanks. I don't have access to the list of files required for the assembly so I cannot upload a zip of all files. I trigger a translation of an assembly file with the intention of it failing. I then see which supporting files were missing, I locate those files, upload the files, set references, then translate the assembly again. Currently your api does not offer any other way to get the files that are required by an assembly file. Could you add that functionality?

Regardless, this does not address the issue that setting references to supporting iam files appears not to work. Please advise.

Comment: Sorry I missed your reply. Yes, currently, no web service tells the referenced files for the root file before translating. I can log a wish on your behalf. While   for the original issue, could you provide me with a demo dataset? I am afraid I misunderstood your question, I need to give a test. You can email me at xiaodong.liang@autodesk.com. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I will prepare a demo and send it to you.